# Unable to get handle on openGL ES variables

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm using the following vertex shader found in a tutorial :

```
                "uniform mat4 matriceDessin;" +
                "uniform mat4 matriceVueCamera;" +
                "uniform vec3 positionLumiere;" +
                "attribute vec4 positionsSommets;" +
                "attribute vec3 vecteursNormaux;" +
                "attribute vec4 couleursSommets;" +

                "varying vec4 v_Color;" +

                "void main() {" +
                    "vec3 sommet,vecteurNormal,directionLumiere;"+
                    "float distance,diffuse;" +

                    "sommet = vec3(matriceVueCamera * positionsSommets);" +
                    "vecteurNormal = vec3(matriceVueCamera * vec4(vecteursNormaux, 0.0));" +
                    "distance = length(positionLumiere - sommet);" +
                    "directionLumiere = normalize(positionLumiere - sommet);" +
                    "diffuse = max(dot(vecteurNormal, directionLumiere), 0.1);" +
                    "diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.25 * distance * distance)));" +
                    "v_Color = couleursSommets;" +

                    "gl_Position = matriceDessin * positionsSommets;" +
                "}";
```

To get the location of my variables, I use, after having successfully created and linked the program :

```
            GLES31.glUseProgram(programme);
            pointeurSurPosition = GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(programme, "positionsSommets");
            pointeurSurVecteurNormal = GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(programme, "vecteursNormaux");
            pointeurSurPositionLumière = GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(programme, "positionLumiere");
            pointeurSurMatriceDessin = GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(programme, "matriceDessin");
            pointeurSurMatriceVueCaméra = GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(programme, "matriceVueCamera");
```

The problem I face is that the calls made to retrieve the locations of `matriceVueCamera`, `positionLumiere` and `vecteursNormaux` always return -1 (other location are correctly retrieved).

According to the doc, this could happen if the variables aren't actives, but one can notice they are used in the shader, hence they should be considered actives, at least as far as I understand the concept.

I tried to bind location to this variables with `glBindAttribLocation`before linking the program but it didn't help.

Does anyone sees where my problem could be?

I use Open GL ES 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local variable `diffuse` is calculated by but never use in the program. Since the shader code is optimized by the driver, this causes that all the code is discarded, which is used to calculate `diffuse`.
Since the uniform variables `matriceVueCamera`, `positionLumiere` and `vecteursNormaux` are necessary only, to calculate `diffuse`, they don't become an active program resources. They are not needed to process the program.

Probably you missed to use `diffuse`, when `v_Color` is calculated:

```c
v_Color = couleursSommets * diffuse ;
```

See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00 Specification - 2.12.6 Uniform Variables; page 58](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf):

> 7.6 Uniform Variables
>
> Shaders can declare named uniform variables, as described in the OpenGL ES Shading Language Specification. Values for these uniforms are constant over a
>   primitive, and typically they are constant across many primitives. A uniform is considered active if it is determined by the compiler and linker that the uniform
>   will actually be accessed when the executable code is executed. In cases where the compiler and linker cannot make a conclusive determination, the uniform will be
>   considered active.

Comment: You are right! The missing "diffuse" use was a consequence of my different attempts to get anything else than a not linked program or a black screen. Now, I get handles on my variables, but my screen desesperatly remains black when the vertex colour is multiplied by "diffuse". Still have to investigate, probably in the direction of the data rather than the shader's code...

Comment: @Zelig63 Possibly `diffuse` less than 0.0 or near to 0.0. Try  `v_Color = couleursSommets * (0.5 + 0.5*max(0.0, diffuse));` for debug reasons.

Comment: Tried with a simple `diffuse=0.1f;` right before multiplying the colour : the object is hard to see, but it is definitively there...

Comment: The problem seems to be related with the `distance` variable. If I set it to 1.0 just after the line where it's calculated, I get a realistic enough lighting of my scene.

Comment: My last problem was an attenuation factor increasing far to quickly as distance increases for the location data I defined. Screen in not blank anymore. Thanks again for your help Rabbid76!